# volume raise indication dialog in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

In my app I want to display an dialog(a screen indicating volume level) when user press VOLUME_UP and VolUme_down keys in the Blackberry Phone,Now I increase or decrase volume when user clicks those keys:

public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
            if(volume != null){
                int key = Keypad.key(keycode);
                if(key == Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_DOWN){
                    volume.setLevel(volume.getLevel()-10);
                }
                else if(key == Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_UP){
                    volume.setLevel(volume.getLevel()+10);
                }

```
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I need  dialog which like in Blackberry phone when users take  songs(and press volume keys) in blackberry Media folder. If any one have idea please help,Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, that using keyDown() for VOLUME_DOWN and keyUp() for VOLUME_UP is correct? :-)

Comment: yea,Its working or both can write in key Down method

Comment: I solved it using add setStatus method, in a different way not as I wished,expecting correct solutions